# Centre of Mass; Block sliding over a wedge; Apply conservation of momentum and energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation, free-body-diagram

A small block of mass m is kept over a triangular wedge of mass M kept over a smooth horizontal surface. Assume that there is no friction between block and wedge. Calculate the velocity of wedge when the block reaches the bottom end. **Use linear momentum conservation and mechanical energy conservation.**  *Please don't use NLM as I have done it below as mentioned.*

[image]

I approached the question using non inertial frame of reference. Calculating acceleration of the block and wedge. Finding time (t) to reach the bottom end as (2h/a sin(x));a(acc. of block downwards).And then applied v = u+bt ; (u=0 as initially the system is at rest; b = acc. of wedge leftwards)
Ans = [{2hm^2 gcos^2(x)}/{(M+m)(M+msin^2(x))}]^(1/2)

x : is the angle of inclination of the wedge.

**Please help me to solve the question by taking velocity of block in wedge's frame and then applying momentum and energy conservation.**
*I am facing problem in writing the momentum conservation equation.*

Thanks for reading it... and helping me out in advance...